# ui-router resolve multiple values inside callback

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angularjs 1.6 and ui-router.

I am resolving data from a rest api to bind to a component in a ui-router state. The code below works but the server also returns a header: 'X-Total-Count', and I need to bind that to the component too.

How can I access the headers returned in that request and use them to set other resolved values?

The ui-router state:

```
$stateProvider.state({
  name: 'customers',
  url: '/customers?page&query',
  component: 'customerTable',
  resolve: {
    customers: function(Customer, $stateParams) {
      // a lot of code here to set the filter...
      return Customer.find({filter: filter})
        .$promise
        .then(
          function(res) {
            return res;
          }
        );
    },
    totalCount: function() {
      // How can I set this from the response returned above?
    }
  }
});
```

and the component:

```
.component('customerTable', {
  templateUrl: 'customer-table.html',
  controller: CustomerTableCtrl,
  bindings: {
    customers: '<',
    totalCount: '<'
  }
})
```

Also, I'm using LoopBack 3 on the server. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. Posting here for future reference. Key points are:

- Use callback on Customer.find() instead of `$promise.then()` so I can access the headers
- Wrap Customer.find() in $q so it returns a promise
- Resolve functions for `customers:` and `totalCount:` wait for the `data:` promise to resolve

Code:

```
resolve: {
  limit: function() {
    return 100; // max items per page
  },
  page: function($stateParams) {
    return parseInt($stateParams.page) || 1;
  },
  query: function($stateParams) {
    return $stateParams.query;
  },
  filter: function(limit, page, query) {
    // use limit, page and query
    // to create the filter object here...
  },
  data: function(Customer, filter, $q) {
    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
      Customer.find({filter: filter}, function(data, headers) {
        resolve({
          customers: data,
          totalCount: headers('x-total-count')
        });
      }, function(err) {
        reject('error');
      });
    });
  },
  customers: function(data) {
    return data.customers;
  },
  totalCount: function(data) {
    return data.totalCount;
  }
}
```